# 23.x - Keep display active when TV turns off

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

**Description:**

I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 on an Intel NUC that has 4 TV's attached.
We're merely using it to display metrics in the office.

I wrote a script that turns off the TV's at 6PM, and turns them on at 7AM.
The issue is that when the TVs power off, they are removed as a display and so when the TV turns on (one after another) all 4 (Firefox) windows are stacked on top of each other on the first monitor that turns on.

I can fix that manually (via VNC) by minimizing all windows and then maximizing again, but it defeats the purpose of automated power cycling the TV's each day.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to keep the displays available even though the TVs are powered off?
Or alternatively; how can I make sure the displays recover their correct (assigned) window when the display setup changes?

---

I found similar questions where I couldn't find a fitting solution:

- [How to disable auto configuration of displays?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397092/how-to-disable-auto-configuration-of-displays)
- [How can I stop Ubuntu from automatically changing my display configuration whenever my TV is turned on/off?](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/da6l8z/how_can_i_stop_ubuntu_from_automatically_changing/)
- [Disabling display auto detection on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364575/disabling-display-auto-detection-on-ubuntu-20-04)
- [How to disable auto configuration of displays?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397092/how-to-disable-auto-configuration-of-displays)

Comment: You should be able to use `xdotool` and/or `wmctrl` to automate the resize/position of all the windows as per your "alternative". I have used `xdotool` to emulate keypresses and `wmctrl` to setup hotkeys for maximising/focusing certain app windows etc.

Comment: I've looked into `wmctrl`, from what I've seen (examples) you have to target a window using a title. Sadly due to "tab rotation" in Firefox the title is not static.
Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this is not fitting as alternative.